# How can I get InDesign CS6 to stop re-apply text from masters when I add a new page?

Tags: adobe-indesign, master-page

This is best explained in picture. Here is the master as set up:

[image: master page]

Here is the spread before I add a new page:

[image: before new page]

And then here's what happens after I try to add a new page (noticed the super-imposed text near the bottom of the image):

[image]

I have to add to this document as is and I don't know how to continue without ruining it. Help?

Comment: is the problem that the Quote is appearing on the page, or that the text is not wrapping around it.
Any object on the Master will appear on a page that the Master has been applied too.

Answer (score 2):

Any object on the Master will appear on a page that the Master has been applied too.

1. You can delete the quote from the Master, and put it on your working page instead.
2. Duplicate your Master, delete the quote, then apply the new Master to the page.
3. If the problem is that the text is just not wrapping around the quote:

   Go to the Master and make new Text boxes for where the edit should flow. Set them so they leave space for the quote.

   Then go back to your working page and delete the text boxes that are there.

   Re-place/insert the edit and just click the the icon where you know your first Text box was drawn. The edit will flow through that space, thus leaving following where you drew the new boxes on the Master.

Answer (score 1):

A Master Page is what its name implies: a master. Its purpose is to allow you to set up repeating elements such as folios (page numbers), running footers/heads, margins, columns and guides so that you don't have to add them by hand on every new page.

No *content* should exist on a master page, nor anything else that you don't want on *every* page associated with that master. Perhaps a good way to think of it is that it's like blank letterhead paper, which has the company logo, name, etc., but no content.

Your solution here is to remove all the text except the folios, rules, section header and running footer from the master page. Leave the text frames if you must, and use Ctl/Cmd-Shift-click to activate them on each live page.